# How to run pg_dump and pg_restore in bat file

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

I have a few Postgres database related command to run, and I want to create a bat file in windows to run them altogether. This is the bat file I created:

```
cd C:\\Program Files\\pgAdmin 4\\v6\\runtime
start pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\Desktop\\dialpad.sql" --host "host1" --port "5432" --username "warehouse" --no-password --verbose --format=c --blobs --schema "dialpad" "pangea_warehouse_production"
SET "PGPASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
start psql --host=host2 --port=5432 --dbname=pangea_warehouse_production --username=warehouse --command="DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS dialpad CASCADE;CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dialpad AUTHORIZATION warehouse;GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA dialpad TO reporting;GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA dialpad TO warehouse;"
start pg_restore.exe --host "host2" --port "5432" --username "warehouse" --dbname "pangea_warehouse_production" --verbose --schema "dialpad" "C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\Desktop\\dialpad.sql"
```

When I run the script, it will give me an error: 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.

Please advise how to fix this issue. Thanks

Comment: the command shell doesn't like spaces so you need to add a "dir" so that it understands that all is a path

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I am not sure if I understand correctly. Like this ? start C:\\Program Files\\pgAdmin 4\\v6\\runtime\\pg_dump.exe --file "C:\\Users\\ADMINI~1\\Desktop\\dialpad.sql" --host "host1" --port "5432" --username "warehouse" --no-password --verbose --format=c --blobs --schema "dialpad" "pangea_warehouse_production"
SET "PGPASSWORD=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: I think nbk meant the first line, with cd. Though yes explicitely writing out the dir of each exe will work. (You might want to consider adding the pgsql bin directory to your PATH env. var)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the path, as i said the shell and your batch file is that, doesn't understand spaces in path as it think that this is a stop condition. it is from old msdos and it is still valid

```
cd "C:\\Program Files\\pgAdmin 4\\v6\\runtime"
```

Comment: That's a bit odd though. Doesn't cd understand bare pathes with spaces in them? Or are there different rules when using a batch file?

Comment: no as i said it thinks that the second part after the space belongs to a parameter, but first it check C:\Program works which it doesn't thus you get an error

Comment: also this is a windows cmd shell command, which you should with errors test first

Comment: That's not what I meant. The command extensions are enabled by default in all shell instances (or at least they should be), which means cd will not consider the space as a separator between parameters and, theoretically, should understand the whole path. i literally just ran a .bat with `cd \program files` , `echo | dir` and it worked as expected.

Comment: no, that is how msdos cmd shell works, it doesn't matter what is enabled or not, it in the core, so it will never change

Comment: Yes it is? I'm a bit confused but we must not be talking about the same thing.

Comment: that is already so old that most windows user that use the command shell regularly have learned and used for it  years, without that is mentioned any more